# Appending html is not working

Tags: jquery

I am not able to append the value of htmlMon to a select box with id 'monValue' in my jsp.
I am getting the required values in htmlMon.

```
$(document).off('change','input:radio[name="monType"]').on('change','input:radio[name="monType"]',function(){

    var type = $(this).val();

    if (type != "") {
        $.post('/sams/monitor/'+type, {
            type : $(this).val(),
            ajax : 'true'
        }, function(data) {
            var htmlMon = '';
            $('#monValue').html(htmlMon);
            var len = data.length;
            for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                htmlMon += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name + '</option>';                         
            }

            $('#monValue').append(htmlMon);
            $('#monValue').trigger('update-select-list').change();
        },
        'json');
    } else {
        var emptyHtml = '';

        $('#monValue').html(emptyHtml);
        $('#monValue').trigger('update-select-list').change();
   }
 });
```

here is the Html

```
<p class="inline-label"> <label class="label">Positive/Negative</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input id="publishRadio" type="radio" name="monType" value="Positive" checked="checked" /> Positive &nbsp; <input type="radio" name="monType" value="Negative"/> Negative </p> <p class="inline-label"> <input type="hidden" value="" /> <label class="label">Select Monitoring</label> <select style="width: 150px; padding: 5px;" id="monValue"> <c:forEach items="${lookupTypes}"var="ltps"> <option value="${ltps.id}">${ltps.name}</option></c:forEach></select></p>
```

Please help me.

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML.

Comment: What do you get in response for data? (Seems to be null/empty)

Comment: @JoakimM I am getting array of 2 objects and i can see the value of htmlMon while debugging as "<option value="54">Good</option><option value="55">Better</option>"

Comment: @Tichodroma <p class="inline-label">

    <label class="label">Positive/Negative</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input
     id="publishRadio" type="radio" name="monType" value="Positive"
     checked="checked" /> Positive &nbsp; <input type="radio"
     name="monType" value="Negative"/> Negative

   </p>
   <p class="inline-label">
    <input type="hidden" value="" /> <label class="label">Select
     Monitoring</label> <select style="width: 150px; padding: 5px;"
 id="monValue">
   <c:forEach items="${lookupTypes}"var="ltps">
<option value="${ltps.id}">${ltps.name}</option></c:forEach></select></p>

Comment: anybody please help me....

Comment: Do you see any error in console?

Comment: @user3925230 Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25302385/edit) and include the HTML in it.

Comment: @s-rupali no. i didn't

Comment: Is it data.length that returns wrong? Do you get the number of elements there?

Comment: @JoakimM Yes i get the number of elements as 2.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, the `option` tags are without the `input type=select` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `append()` try using `html()` because you're already replacing existing options of select box with an `empty string`. I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srupali/syqL55p1/) with static values and its working fine.

So your jQuery code could be like this after getting the response from ajax request:

```
        var htmlMon = '';
        $('#monValue').html(htmlMon);
        var len = data.length;
        for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            htmlMon += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name + '</option>';                         
        }

        $('#monValue').html(htmlMon);
        $('#monValue').trigger('update-select-list').change();
```